# using ColumnTransformer for predicting values

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, regression

I am currently running a logistic regression model using keras.

I have 1 numeric variable and around 6 categorical variables.

I am currently using a column transformer for training and testing the model and it works perfect (code shown below):

```
numeric_variables = ["var1"]
cat_variables = ["var2","var3","var4","var5","var6","var7"]

pipeline = ColumnTransformer([('num',StandardScaler(), numeric_variables), ('cat',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore"), cat_variables)], remainder = "passthrough")

pipeline.fit(X_Train)

pipeline.fit_transform(X_Train)
```

This works perfectly when I run the train and test dataset.

However, when I deploy the model to get the probability of a customer renewing, I am sending the data as a dataframe with one row.

While the fit_transform for X_Train and X_Test gives out a nx17 array (because of the onehotencoding of the 7 factors), the transform of the predictions only gives nx7.

My theory here is that the pipeline is dropping one hot encoded fields.  For instance, if var2 can take 3 values (say "M","F" and "O"), the X_Train gives out 3 columns for each (isM, isF and isO) while the transform for the predictions is only giving the output for "isM" if the value of Var2 is "M"

How do I address this issue?

I get this error when I run the model.predict on the single customer example:

```
Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 19), found shape=(None, 7)
```

Comment: Can you show a sample row of a datapoint and the call that generates that error, too?

Comment: You need to persist the fitted transformers (pickle and friends), then call just `transform` on the producing row.

Comment: I am pickling the transform when im training the model... i then unpickle the transform and use fit_transform...im still getting this

Comment: @galeej you shouldn't use `fit_transform`, but only `transform`. What you are doing is re-fitting the encoder with only the classes that are in the test sample. Instead, use the fitted model with `.transform(X)`

Comment: @galeej no problem, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments:

It appears that you are using [`pipeline.fit_transform(X_test)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_transform). This means you are fitting your pipeline with `X_test` before transforming it. This is a problem in your case for two reasons:

- You are re-fitting the `StandardScaler`, which means you will scale your features differently than what you did with the train set.
- You are re-fitting the `OneHotEncoder`. Hence, you could miss some categories in `cat_variables` that were present only in the train set. Consequently, your output shape is smaller.

Simply use [`.transform(X_train)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.transform) instead.